# (Python/VS Code) Can't install scipy

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scipy

I seem to be unable to install scipy using VS Code.

python -m pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
Using cached scipy-1.5.2.tar.gz (25.4 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing wheel metadata ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmkxabgvf'
cwd: C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4lff1348\scipy
Complete output (195 lines):
setup.py:460: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-j_sx_haa'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
Running from SciPy source directory.
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs']
NOT AVAILABLE

```
openblas_lapack_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\bundyjas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\bundyjas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem',
```

'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
customize PGroupFlangCompiler
Could not locate executable flang
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
NOT AVAILABLE

```
openblas_clapack_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\bundyjas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\bundyjas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

flame_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\bundyjas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\bundyjas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs        
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

accelerate_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\bundyjas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\bundyjas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-eitrbrks\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-eitrbrks\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
  NOT AVAILABLE

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
  File "C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-eitrbrks\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 161, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    self.run_setup()
  File "C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-eitrbrks\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 253, in run_setup
    super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
  File "C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-eitrbrks\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
    exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
  File "setup.py", line 583, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 579, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-eitrbrks\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 477, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError(msg)
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\bundyjas\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmkxabgvf' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 1):

Installing scipy from source is *pretty harsh* and not recommended, especially on windows. Your logs already indicate that there is a need for C/C++/Fortran compilers, the latter being used for OpenBLAS. (Before 1.0, there were years without official binary releases!)

Installing from source happens, when there is no fitting pre-made binary found, like in your case.

The reason here: you are using Python 3.9, which is just too new (October 5th: < 2 weeks now). There is **no official pre-made scipy release yet**. [Hint](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/1.5.2/#files)

Go for Python <= 3.8. (Trust me: you don't want to install from source on windows).

(This is totally unrelated / orthogonal to VS Code)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with a fresh Miniconda install and things worked out.

Comment: Why don't you accept the answer then, given it helped you?